# I want to ignore "apt-get -f install"

Tags: apt

When I want to install a new package, I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet de pendencies:
cndrvcups-capt:i386 : Depends: cndrvcups-common:i386 (>= 2.60) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But if I run it, it will purge my printer driver!

I want to force install new software without any attention to `apt-get -f install`. Is it possible someway?

Update:

The canon driver for LBP series is not exist in any repo. It have a two version for 32 and 64 bit machines. But, the 64 bit package is not a real 64 bit package! It depends on i386 packages! So, people should install 32 bit package, then 64 bit one on their 64-bit machines to make it work. And, this brings `apt-get -f install`! If you run *apt-get -f install*, then it remove the driver:

```
The following packages have unmet de pendencies:
cndrvcups-capt:i386 : Depends: cndrvcups-common:i386 (>= 2.60) 
but it is not installable
```

`apt-get -f install`:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED: cndrvcups-capt:i386, 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install cndrvcups-common:i386` say?

Comment: Dear @Ron, It says: "E: Package 'cndrvcups-common:i386' has no installation candidate"; It does not exist in the repositories. It should be install manually: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `cndrvcups-capt:i386` with:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Download and install the driver package with these steps:

```
cd
wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100004596/03/Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz
tar xv xf Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN.tar.gz
```

- 64-bit

  ```
  cd Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian
  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_amd64.deb
  ```
- 32-bit

  In my case, the following libraries have been required:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libglade2-0:i386
  sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0:i386
  sudo apt-get install libpopt0:i386
  ```

  and than:

  ```
  cd Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/32-bit_Driver/Debian
  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386.deb
  ```

Comment: I've do it many times! I've added a new part to the end of my question. Please take a glance again.